# How to make redirect based on the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make the users add to urls, the first url will redirect to the second url in the database. I have two columns redirect and redirect to the user add to the database successfully the nest step is to make the url redirect depending on the urls on the database
from `redirectfrom` to `redirecto`.

```
public void RedirectUrl(string sourceUrl)
{
    using (DrWaelGhanemEntities context = new DrWaelGhanemEntities())
    {
        RedirectUrlsTable redirectRule = context.RedirectUrlsTables
            .FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.RedirectFrom == sourceUrl);

        if (redirectRule != null)
        {
            string destinationUrl = redirectRule.RedirectTo;

            // Check if the destination URL is the same as the source URL.
            if (string.Equals(sourceUrl, destinationUrl, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // Handle this case to prevent a redirection loop.
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(destinationUrl, endResponse: true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // No matching rule found; you can handle this case as needed.
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error of "too many redirects".

This is the `Global.asax` file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
    bool found = false;
    string URL = String.Empty;

    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("cpanel") && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains(".axd") && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("localhost") && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("platform"))
    {
        if (!builder.Host.Contains("www"))
        {
            builder.Host = "www." + builder.Host;
            found = true;
        }

        URL = builder.ToString();
        URL = Server.UrlDecode(URL);
    }

    if (URL.EndsWith("/") && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("cpanel") && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains(".axd") && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("localhost") && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("platform"))
    {
        found = true;
        URL = URL + "/";
    }

    if (found && !Request.Url.IsLoopback)
    {
        Response.RedirectPermanent(URL, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? What is the values of the variables when your code hit the controller? Too many redirects mean you keep giving Redirect response.

Comment: the variables are correct not the same values and it's added to the DB correctly when i debugging isn't really useful because in localhost when i debug i get redirected to the home page but when i deploy the code on the server i get the error the whole website is not working

Comment: Then you will have to log the values on your server and see why it's happening, or simulate it on your localhost (by assigning to a variable and manually set it in `#if DEBUG` for example)